# iOS 14 background fetch gives scheduling error

Tags: ios, ios14, background-task, background-fetch

I've been trying to implement background fetch in my app for iOS 13 and 14.x Here's the steps I followed

1. Enable Background fetch mode in the project capabilities
2. In the info.plist, add an array for key `BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers` with the relevant id for bkg fetch task
3. In the `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, register the background task

```
BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: bkgTaskId, using: nil) { (task) in
  self.handleAppRefreshTask(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
}
```

4. `handleAppRefreshTask(task: BGAppRefreshTask)` handles the background task. It has the `expirationHandler` set and marks task completed once done
5. At the end of the above method, schedule the task to be fired after an interval of 1 hour (or whenever iOS schedules it)

```
    func scheduleRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: bkgTaskId)
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600)
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            Log("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

6. In `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, call `scheduleRefresh` to schedule the background task

When I simulate the background fetch task from Xcode (running the app on a device), I get the below in the console and the background task is never scheduled

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x28138ef40 - WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager: Ignored request to start a new background task because RunningBoard has already started the expiration timer
```

Anything on what I might be doing wrong or how to fix this would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?